# Error: Invalid identifier ' conList '. Apex identifiers must start with an ASCII letter (a-z or A-Z) followed by any number

Tags: trigger, contact

```
trigger preventDuplication on Contact (before insert) { 

  List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>();

    conList = [SELECT LastName, Phone, Email FROM Contact];

    for(Contact con : Trigger.New){

        if(conList.size() > 0){

            for(Contact c : conList){

                if(c.Phone == con.Phone){

                    con.addError('Account already Exist with Phone Number');

                }else if(c.Email == con.Email){

                    con.addError('Account Already Exist with Email');

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You have to define a list type like this: `List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>();`

Comment: @MartinLezer the `<Contact>`s were just getting hidden because of the formatting.

Comment: Occasionally you can get characters that are not visible in code, particularly when code is copied from documentation. Delete and re-type all the characters around any instance of `conList`.

Comment: I don't really understand all the downvotes on this question. Sure, the question could be better posed (error messages aren't well suited for titles, the problem statement and question aren't explicitly included, etc...) but it has the important parts (error message, and the relevant code). I wouldn't usually upvote this, but I will in this case because of all of the drive-by-downvoters (those who downvote without leaving an explanation). I would, however, suggest moving the error message into the question proper, and changing the title to something like "Code looks fine but won't compile"

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything visibly wrong with the code you've provided. As Keith C mentioned in the comments, you can occasionally get invisible (unprintable) characters when you copy/paste code.

If the code looks right, but it throws some mysterious error, invisible characters are a likely explanation.

Typing out your existing code (again, by hand this time) should take care of the issue.

Beyond that, I'd recommend making some changes to your trigger. A nested loop will work, but using a nested loop to compare values from two collections (a `List` is a type of collection) is slow. Querying all of your `Contact` records is also unsustainable. Once you have enough `Contacts` in your org, you will start to get query selectivity errors.

A better approach would be to loop over your incoming `Contacts`, and build a `Map` or two. The idea is that we can avoid the nested loop by figuring out which phone numbers/emails we need to check *before querying for existing `Contacts`*.

```java
trigger myTrigger on Contact(before Insert){
    // I use a Map<String, List<Contact>> here, because it is entirely possible that two (or more)
    //   incoming contacts have the same phone number
    Map<String, List<Contact>> phoneNumsToContacts = new Map<String, List<Contact>>();

    for(Contact c :Trigger.new){
        // First, we check to see if the current phone number already exists in the map
        if(!phoneNumsToContacts.containsKey(c.Phone)){
            // If we get to this line, the phone number doesn't yet exist in the map.
            // So, we put the phone number into the map.
            // You could add the current contact to the new List immediately,
            //   but I personally prefer not to.
            // Doing things this way means we don't need to worry about making an else
            //   block (which also ends up being a bit more DRY [don't repeat yourself]).
            phoneNumsToContacts.put(c.Phone, new List<Contact>());
        }

        // At this point, we are guaranteed to have the phone number in the map.
        // All we need to worry about is adding the contact to the list
        phoneNumsToContacts.get(c.Phone).add(c);
    }

    // The syntax below, for(Type name :[query]), is called a "SOQL for loop", and is
    //   very efficient.
    // Also, querying for specific field values (such as the phone numbers we have encountered,
    //   which we have in the keyset of the map we built earlier) can make a query much
    //   more selective.
    // Phone isn't an indexed field, unfortunately, so we don't get that benefit here.
    // Email, however, is an indexed field; you'll see the benefit when you extend this
    //   example to include emails as well.
    for(Contact c :[SELECT Id, Phone FROM Contact WHERE Phone IN :phoneNumsToContacts.keySet()]){
        // OK, I lied a little...we still have a nested loop.
        // The difference is that this inner loop will likely only have 1, maybe 2
        //   records to iterate over (as opposed to iterating over all of your existing
        //   contacts, multiple times).
        for(Contact incomingContact :phoneNumsToContacts.get(c.Phone)){
            // I  haven't tested this, but believe it should work
            incomingContact.addError('Duplicate Phone Number detected!');

            // The above should work, because the Contact instances stored in phoneNumsToContacts
            //   are the same instance contained in Trigger.new.
            // If that doesn't work, we just need to do a little extra work.
            // Trigger.newMap.get(incomingContact.Id).addError('Duplicate Phone Number detected!');
        }

        // You might also want to check if there are any duplicate phone numbers in your 
        //   incoming Contact records.
        // Making our earlier map makes this easy.
        // Our loop variable here is a List<Contact> because that's the data type of
        //   the values of this particular map
        for(List<Contact> contacts : phoneNumsToContacts.values()){
            // Since the map is keyed on phone number, having a list whose size is 
            //   greater than 1 means we have a duplicate phone number
            if(contacts.size() > 1){
                // This for loop should look nearly identical to the last nested loop
                //   we made.
                for(Contact dupPhone :contacts){
                    dupPhone.addError('Duplicate phone number in incoming contacts');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'll leave including email checking to the above code to you.