# Getting error while writing a simple trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I am getting an error as below while saving the trigger:

> Error : Compile Error: Invalid identifier ''. Apex identifiers must
>   start with an ASCII letter (a-z or A-Z) followed by any number of
>   ASCII letters (a-z or A-Z), digits (0 - 9), '$', '_'.

```
trigger validWorker on Worker__c(before insert, before update){   
  for(Worker__c worker:Trigger.new){  
   if(worker.Type__c =='Chef' && worker.Percent__c <> 10)
    {
      worker.addError('Percentage must be 10%');
    }                                                                       
  }                                                                         
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's missing a closing parenthesis here: `(before insert, before update`

Comment: i hv corrected my question.

Comment: Try copying your code to notepad and then copy paste from there to your Org.

Comment: Same error :( ....

Comment: could be possible because of copy & paste issue, try editing your code in different editor , e.g Notepad++ then paste it into your org.

Comment: yeah..I tired that but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not closing the quote on line `worker.addError('Percentage must be 10%);`
Try the below code

```
trigger validWorker on Worker__c(before insert, before update){   
  for(Worker__c worker:Trigger.new){  
   if(worker.Type__c =='Chef' && worker.Percent__c <> 10)
    {
      worker.addError('Percentage must be 10%');
    }                                                                       
  }                                                                         
}
```

The above code seems to be working for me. Please refer the below link. This might solve your problem.

[Apex Identifiers must start with an ASCII Character](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/175418/error-invalid-identifier-conlist-apex-identifiers-must-start-with-an-ascii)

Comment: Nope..I am still getting the same error. Actually i had closed quote. somehow missed while posting code here in question. I have updated my question.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check again

Comment: Can you please tell me what was i doing wrong ..

Comment: I compared code i posted and your answer. Both are exactly same. I still don't get it, how is that even possible

Comment: As mentioned before, sometimes it because of the editor. Cant help much in that case. Glad that worked out for you

Answer (score 1):

Derek is correct. For a faster fix, however:

1. Paste your broken code into http://cloudandfree.com/en/remove_non_ascii.php
2. Replace all non-ASCII characters with a symbol not in your file (e.g. `$`)
3. In your editor, replace your code with the results from step 2, then find and replace every `$` with an empty space

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this type of issue usually turns out to be caused by invisible characters being included when you copy/paste code. If that's the case, then re-typing the code (not using copy/paste for anything) in question fixes the issue.

Yes, it can be a pain to re-type things, but you'd probably spend as much time (if not more) trying to track down one of the many unprintable UTF-8 characters that could be included.