# Invalid identifier ' '. error on running code in anonymous window

Tags: apex, soql, json

I am trying to learning JSON Serialization from [developer.salesforce.com](https://developer.salesforce.com) in which i came accross a code snippet which i tried to run in anonymous window.

```
Contact con = [SELECT Id, LastName, AccountId FROM Contact LIMIT 1]; 
// Set additional field
con.FirstName = 'Joe'; 
String jsonstring = Json.serialize(con); 
System.debug(jsonstring); 
System.assert(jsonstring.contains('Joe') == true);
```

on executing i am getting error as

> "Line: 1, Column: 69 Invalid identifier ' '. Apex identifiers must
> start with an ASCII letter (a-z or A-Z) followed by any number of
> ASCII letters (a-z or A-Z), digits (0 - 9), '$', '_'.".

Not able to understand why.

Comment: The code is running fine for me. I think there is some formatting issue for you. can you try typing the code?

Comment: Note that line 1 ends at column 69 and hence, the error could possibly be caused by invisible char. Does this answer your question? [Getting error while writing a simple trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/206968/getting-error-while-writing-a-simple-trigger)

Comment: Typing the same code helped